# Homeomorphism between $S^1$ and $[0,1]/ 0\sim1$

Tags: general-topology, functions

I'm studying quotient spaces in my topology course.
I want to prove that circle $S^1=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2=1 \}$ homeomorphic to $[0,1]/ 0\sim1$ (segment with the identified points). 
To solve this problem, I use the following theorem:

> If $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ is continuous and surjective map, $X$ is compact, $Y$ is Hausdorff then the map $f/S(f): X/S(f) \longrightarrow Y$ is homeomorphism.

So if we assume the map $f: [0,1]\longrightarrow S^1$ by the rule $f(t)=(\cos(2\pi t),\sin(2\pi t))$. This map and spaces satisfy all the conditions of theorem. So $S^1\approx [0,1]/ 0\sim1$

But I think that the use of this theorem is not necessary here. Maybe you know any other ways to solve this problem.

Edit:
A map $f : X \longrightarrow Y$ determines the partition of the set X into nonempty
preimages of the elements of Y . This partition is denoted by $S(f)$.

Comment: I changed $S_1$ to $S^1$ in your post.  $S_1$ is the symmetric group on one element.

Comment: What is $\,S(f)\,$ in your post?

Comment: This theorem is a direct consequence of the universal property of quotient spaces. So that's a very natural way to prove the result.

Comment: It's actually two theorems combined. The first one which states that a continuous function from a compact space into a Hausdorff space is closed. And the second one which states that an identification function $f:X\to Y$ (that is a surjective function such that $Y$ has the final topology with regards to $f$) induces a homeomorphism $\hat f:X/S(f)\to Y$. In particular, closed surjections are identification maps.

Comment: @DonAntonio I've edited my question.

Comment: I see, caloric. Thus, $\,X/S(f)\,$ is just the quotient space of the equivalence classes determined by the partition $\,S(f)\,$ of $\,X\,$...but then what you want to prove follows almost at once: why would you want to prove it in other way?

Comment: @DonAntonio I have just started learning this, and I thought that there may be other ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to go in the other direction if you want to avoid the universal property of quotient spaces (which is the most natural approach for the direction $[0,1]/\sim\longrightarrow S^1$, and can not really be avoided).

Let $\log z$ denote the principal branch of $\log$ on$\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$. Recall that in particular, $\log$ is continuous and $\log(e^{i\theta})=i\theta $ for all $\theta$ in $(-\pi,\pi)$.

Now consider the map
$$
f:z\longmapsto \frac{\frac{1}{i}\log z +\pi}{2\pi}.
$$
It is a continuous bijection from $S^1\setminus \{-1\}$ onto $(0,1)$.

By composition with the canonical surjection $x\longmapsto [x]$ of $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1]/\sim$, we get
$$
\bar{f}:z\longmapsto \left[\frac{\frac{1}{i}\log z +\pi}{2\pi}\right]
$$
continuous from $S^1\setminus \{-1\}$ to $\left[0,1\right]/\sim$.

Now 
$$
\lim_{z\rightarrow -1} \bar{f}(z)=[0]=[1].
$$
So we can extend $\bar{f}$ by continuity to a continuous $\bar{f}:S^1\longrightarrow [0,1]/\sim $.

It is clear that $\bar{f}$ is a continuous bijection.

Since $S^1$ is compact, it is a homeomorphism.